# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: db2, spring-batch-admin

I have used odbc6 driver to connect to the DB2 database. When i try to run job using spring batch i am getting the below error message can some one  help me to fix the issue. I am not using any server here, i have included the required jars in the classpath and run the batch using run configuration in Eclipse. Also i am using
hibernate.cfg file to configure the context.

> ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath:
>   log4j2.xml ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found.
>   Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
>   15:06:27.268 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR
>   com.usaa.fts.batch.pepplus.listeners.WriterListenerLogger - Error
>   writing object
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver
>   of class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' for connect URL 'null'   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
>   ~[inf-spring-batch-fixes.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:681)
>   ~[inf-spring-batch-fixes.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:997)
>   ~[inf-spring-batch-fixes.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:361)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:181)
>   ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   com.usaa.inf.batch2.writers.UsaaJdbcBatchItemWriter.writeItems(UsaaJdbcBatchItemWriter.java:85)
>   ~[inf-batch-impl-2.0.jar:?]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.writeItems(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]  at
>   org.springframework.batch.jsr.item.ItemWriterAdapter.write(ItemWriterAdapter.java:55)
>   ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrChunkProcessor.doPersist(JsrChunkProcessor.java:243)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.doWithRetry(JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:298)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
>   [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:168)
>   [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:222)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor.persist(JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:348)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrChunkProcessor.process(JsrChunkProcessor.java:114)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
>   [spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
>   [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
>   [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
>   [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.job.flow.support.state.JsrStepState.handle(JsrStepState.java:53)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.job.flow.JsrFlowJob.doExecute(JsrFlowJob.java:82)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator$2.run(JsrJobOperator.java:675)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144] Caused by:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver
>   of class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' for connect URL 'null'   at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1169)
>   ~[com.springsource.org.apache.commons.dbcp-1.2.2.osgi.jar:?]  at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:882)
>   ~[com.springsource.org.apache.commons.dbcp-1.2.2.osgi.jar:?]  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    ... 48 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.acceptsURL(OracleDriver.java:638)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1160)
>   ~[com.springsource.org.apache.commons.dbcp-1.2.2.osgi.jar:?]  at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:882)
>   ~[com.springsource.org.apache.commons.dbcp-1.2.2.osgi.jar:?]  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]    ... 48 more
>   15:06:28.799 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR
>   com.usaa.fts.batch.pepplus.listeners.WriterListenerLogger - Could not
>   cast exception java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException cannot be
>   cast to java.sql.BatchUpdateException     at
>   com.usaa.fts.batch.pepplus.listeners.WriterListenerLogger.onWriteError(WriterListenerLogger.java:37)
>   [bin/:?]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>   [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.onWriteError(Unknown Source) [?:?]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.ItemWriteListenerAdapter.onWriteError(ItemWriteListenerAdapter.java:68)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeItemWriteListener.onWriteError(CompositeItemWriteListener.java:86)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.listener.MulticasterBatchListener.onWriteError(MulticasterBatchListener.java:303)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrChunkProcessor.doPersist(JsrChunkProcessor.java:247)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.doWithRetry(JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:298)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
>   [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:168)
>   [spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:222)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor.persist(JsrFaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:348)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.step.item.JsrChunkProcessor.process(JsrChunkProcessor.java:114)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
>   [spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
>   [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
>   [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
>   [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.job.flow.support.state.JsrStepState.handle(JsrStepState.java:53)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.job.flow.JsrFlowJob.doExecute(JsrFlowJob.java:82)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator$2.run(JsrJobOperator.java:675)
>   [spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use ojdbc6 to connect to a Db2 database. ojdbc6 is for connecting to databases that use the Oracle RDBMS.

To connect to a Db2-database, you need an installed Db2-driver, and if the Db2-server runs on Z/OS or i-Series then you also need a relevant license (unless your company has a Db2-connect gateway).

For Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows  (or Db2-connect gateways) , Get a suitable Db2-driver [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866). For i-Series, contact your i-Series administrator.

Comment: Yep, I thought the same thing. That's the Oracle JDBC driver. The correct driver is `db2jcc.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding these jars worked for me

1. db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
2. db2jcc4.jar